# My child table is not deleting

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my entity file. Here I have used bidirectional mapping my requirement is,If I delete parent I want delete both parent and child and If I delete child i want to delete only child not parent. But here that is not working  can any one expline me how to do that.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.treamis.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "LibraryBookListTable")
public class LibraryBookListEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "BookListId")
    private int booklistid;
    @Column(name = "ISBN", nullable = false)
    private String isbn;
    @Column(name = "edition", nullable = false)
    private String edition;
    @Column(name = "publisher", nullable = false)
    private String publisher;
    @Column(name = "place", nullable = false)
    private String place;
    @Column(name = "page", nullable = false)
    private String page;
    @Column(name = "source", nullable = false)
    private String source;
    @Column(name = "billno", nullable = false)
    private String billno;
    @Column(name = "callno", nullable = false)
    private String callno;
    @Column(name = "BookTitle", nullable = false)
    private String booktitle;
    @Column(name = "BookAuthor", nullable = false)
    private String author;
    @Column(name = "BookPrice", nullable = false)
    private float price;
    @Column(name = "RackNumber", nullable = false)
    private String rack;
    @Column(name = "PublishedYear", nullable = false)
    private String publishedyear;
    @Column(name = "NoofCopies", nullable = false)
    private int tcopies;
    @Column(name = "DateAdded", nullable = false)
    private java.sql.Date dateAdded;
    @Column(name = "billdate", nullable = false)
    private java.sql.Date billdate;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = CategoryEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_Id", referencedColumnName = "category_Id", nullable = true)
    private CategoryEntity categoryid;
    @OneToOne
    private UserEntity addedBy;
    @OneToOne
    private UserEntity modifiedBy;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    @JoinColumn(name = "BookListId", referencedColumnName = "BookListId")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    private Set< LibraryBarCodeEntity> chield;

    public Set<LibraryBarCodeEntity> getChield() {
        return chield;
    }

    public void setChield(Set<LibraryBarCodeEntity> chield) {
        this.chield = chield;
    }
    //@Column(name = "AddedDate", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date addedate;
    // @Column(name = "ModifiedDate", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date modifiedDate;

    public int getBooklistid() {
        return booklistid;
    }

    public void setBooklistid(int booklistid) {
        this.booklistid = booklistid;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String getBooktitle() {
        return booktitle;
    }

    public void setBooktitle(String booktitle) {
        this.booktitle = booktitle;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getRack() {
        return rack;
    }

    public void setRack(String rack) {
        this.rack = rack;
    }

    public int getTcopies() {
        return tcopies;
    }

    public void setTcopies(int tcopies) {
        this.tcopies = tcopies;
    }

    public java.sql.Date getDateAdded() {
        return dateAdded;
    }

    public void setDateAdded(java.sql.Date dateAdded) {
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }

    public CategoryEntity getCategoryid() {
        return categoryid;
    }

    public void setCategoryid(CategoryEntity categoryid) {
        this.categoryid = categoryid;
    }

    public UserEntity getAddedBy() {
        return addedBy;
    }

    public void setAddedBy(UserEntity addedBy) {
        this.addedBy = addedBy;
    }

    public UserEntity getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(UserEntity modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    public java.util.Date getAddedate() {
        return addedate;
    }

    public void setAddedate(java.util.Date addedate) {
        this.addedate = addedate;
    }

    public java.util.Date getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(java.util.Date modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

//    public String getAccessionnumber() {
//        return accessionnumber;
//    }
//
//    public void setAccessionnumber(String accessionnumber) {
//        this.accessionnumber = accessionnumber;
//    }
    public String getEdition() {
        return edition;
    }

    public void setEdition(String edition) {
        this.edition = edition;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public String getBillno() {
        return billno;
    }

    public void setBillno(String billno) {
        this.billno = billno;
    }

    public String getCallno() {
        return callno;
    }

    public void setCallno(String callno) {
        this.callno = callno;
    }

    public java.sql.Date getBilldate() {
        return billdate;
    }

    public void setBilldate(java.sql.Date billdate) {
        this.billdate = billdate;
    }

    public String getPublishedyear() {
        return publishedyear;
    }

    public void setPublishedyear(String publishedyear) {
        this.publishedyear = publishedyear;
    }
//    public Set< LibraryBarCodeEntity> getChield() {
//        return chield;
//    }
//
//    public void setChield(Set< LibraryBarCodeEntity> chield) {
//        this.chield = chield;
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

alter you table so that it is setup as DELETE CASCADE.

In hibernate this would be like

```
<set name="stockDailyRecords" cascade="delete" table="stock_daily_record" ...>
      <key>
            <column name="STOCK_ID" not-null="true" />
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="com.mkyong.common.StockDailyRecord" />
</set>
```

see this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/)

Comment: I cant able to delete the only child here

Comment: Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: I am sorry My requirement is I want to delete the all the child with out deleting my parent. And If i delete parent the child is also to be delete.

Comment: If you want to delete al children but no the parent then iterate over the children and delete them.  As for automatically deleting all children when the parent to delete, then implement my answer.